# DHCP не раздает ip на wi-fi

Tags: сеть, dhcp, wifi, сервер

Есть сервер на котором настроен DHCP,когда подключаешь к ноутбуку интернет через кабель,то он автоматически присваивает ip и шлюз и все что положено, а когда работаешь через wi-fi нужно присваивать в ручную.Подскажите пожалуйста в чем загвоздка?

Comment: Недостаточно информации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему не включить DHCP на Wi-Fi роутере, и расчитать, чтобы диапазоны выдаваемые DHCP на вышеупомянутом сервере, и на роутере не пересекались? Кстати, модель роутера в студию :)

Comment: у меня сервер и есть роутер,обычный камп с ОС Windows 2003

Comment: если я  вас правильно понял то просто создать еще одну область ip только с другим диапазоном ? или как? а как сервак будет знать кому откуда назначать

Comment: Да вы модель роутера назовите! Мб можно будет сделать в сети второй дхцп

Comment: ну роутера нет,сервер как роутер,в сервак идет интернет  кабель а от сервака через вторую сетевуху в свич вот и все

Answer (score 0):

А на ноуте включена служба беспроводной настройки (WZC)? Или Вы используете другую программу настройки беспроводной сети?

Comment: вот по поводу этой службы не знаю,использую стандартную программу настройки wi-fi которая встроена в виндовс

Comment: Тогда попробуйте проверить настройки сети (вкладка "Беспроводные соединения") и ключ сети. Или же попробуйте установить программу для настройки беспроводной сети именно для Вашего сетевого адаптера. Я, например, не использую стандартную службу настройки, а программу D-Link Wireless Connection Manager, и работает нормально.

Comment: я так понял просто на ноуты установить программы у меня d-link 2100ap точка доступа

Comment: У меня на компе стоит беспроводной адаптер D-Link, а точка доступа -- ASUS. Но настройку сети делает именно прога от D-Link. Посмотрите производителя Вашей сетевухи на ноуте и попробуйте скачать соответствующую прогу настройки сети.

Comment: та просто мне сказали так,хочу прийти в офис с ноутом любым и сразу подключится,как допустим в кафе там все автоматизированно) ну попробую настроить все таки по дхцп

Answer (score 0):

все разобрался что то я вообще затупил) ведь на точке доступа просто нужно было включить DHCP ) настроил его и забыл поставить Enable